# Possible to create a private node behind an ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I was wondering if this was possible. I have an AWS Elastic Load Balancer that currently has three servers behind it. Those three servers are inside of a VPC. What I'm wondering is possible is if I can create a fourth server either inside or outside of the VPC and put that also behind the ELB to leverage the multiple servers CPU but then make that new server a private node only accesible to a certain IP Range. I'd like to throw up another server that I can do server tweaks to for performance and speed that utilizes the ELB to balance CPU usage so I can test, and if that breaks it doesn't affect anybody.

Comment: refer this link https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=95350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be sneaky about this. Nothing says you can't register instances with multiple ELBs, so what you could do is:

1. Setup a brand new ELB.
2. Limit its security group to your narrow IP range.
3. Register your first three servers with the new ELB. They're now registered with two different ELBs.
4. Register your fourth server with the new ELB, but not the old one.
5. Enable traffic from the new ELB's security group into all four instances on whatever port you're using (presumably 80).

That new, secret, IP-limited ELB will distribute traffic across all four instances, but should give you a reasonably fair testbed for the fourth instance. If the fourth instance falls over, it's safe to conclude it'd behave even worse in 0.0.0.0/0 traffic.

Unfortunately, there's no way I know of to say "forward traffic on these ports from these IPs to only this instance" inside an ELB. That defeats its purpose entirely, even if it's really useful in performance tests.

Comment: That's almost a brilliant idea.. Only issue is AWS Route 53 will only let one ELB point to the Zone Apex. I just tried it out. I'm going to keep looking into a solution similar to this.

Comment: Ignore the comment above. I found out how to add multiple apex's.. the only issue is that DNS is assigning users the ELB with the restricted IP Range so it's just blocking them... back to the drawing board.

Comment: Is the IP range under your control?

Comment: @Peter If so, just /etc/hosts those servers. The elb will cycle IPs but not that quickly... I do that for testing stacks all the time.

Comment: Not sure what I mean about doing the /etc/hosts.

Comment: An `/etc/hosts` file is a file used by a computer to map [hostnames to IP addresses.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) A full explanation would take longer than allowed in comments, but basically what you do is `ping <ELB_CNAME>` (the looooong CNAME). Map your domain name to that IP address on your test systems, and then conduct the load test. The IP of ELBs changes, so it's only good for a few hours, but it's one (not awful) way to test ELBs directly. If your app can interpret multiple TLDs, you could also map test.mydomain.com to the ELB CNAME.